# how to change specific value's color in pcolormesh, such as -1,-2,-3, not NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I know there is a func cmap.set_bad to change NaN's color but I want to change color of more values such as -1,-2,-3, how to do it?
this plot is base on basemap
and I want to hold the color of the other area so I can't use the colormap built by myself

```
#####  plot IMERG  ####
latcorners = ([20.05, 54.051])
loncorners = ([73.05, 136.05])
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=latcorners[0],urcrnrlat=latcorners[1],llcrnrlon=loncorners[0],urcrnrlon=loncorners[1])
# Draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.
m.drawcoastlines(color='darkgray')
m.drawstates(color='darkgray')
m.drawcountries(color='darkgray')
# Define the latitude and longitude data
X,Y = np.float32(np.meshgrid(theLons, theLats))
X1,Y1 = np.float16(np.meshgrid(lons_resized, lats_resized))
# Mask the values less than 0 because there is no data to plot.
masked_array = np.ma.masked_where(precip < 0,precip)
# Plot every masked value as grey
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gnuplot').copy()
cmap.set_bad('darkslategray', 1.)

# Draw filled contours.
clevs = np.arange(0,5,0.2)
m.readshapefile(r'../beijing/beijing', 'Shape_Leng', color='darkgrey')

# Plot the data,resized_precip is an ndarray which contains precipitation data, with shape(3401,6301), X1,Y1 are lon/lat of these points 

cs = m.pcolormesh(X1,Y1,resized_precip, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=10)

parallels = np.arange(-90.,91,5.)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[True,False,True,False],color='darkgray')
meridians = np.arange(-180.,180.,10.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[False,False,False,True],color='darkgray')


# Add colorbar
cbar = m.colorbar(cs,location='right',pad="5%")
cbar.set_label('mm/h')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

this is a program which is used to plot some precipitation data.
I want to plot these precipitation data properly,but I want to highlight some specific area with special color, and these points are flaged by special value.so how can I highlight these area by the same way as pcolormesh but not scatter?

Comment: How does your data look like? Are they discrete?  In general, color mapping works with continuous data, which always never are exactly equal to a specific value. Could you also add an image of how things look like without manipulating the color map?  One approach could be to first draw the standard image, and then on top of it images masked for specific values.  It would really help people trying to help you if you created reproducible example code.

Comment: thanks for these tips. data are discrete,so I want to plot thenm by pcolormesh.but iI want to highlight some specific area with special color, and these area are flagged with specific values and are more than one  categories.